# How to open specific url ("Complete action with") with my app?

Tags: android

Is it possible in android to open specific url with app?
For example if in twitter youtube link is shared and i click on it i receive list of intents "Complete action with" and ability to choose web browser or youtube app.

If it possible to add my app to this list if user clicks in twitter on lick www.myapp.com/blog?

I have tried to add in Manifest

```
            <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="myapp.com"
                android:path="/blog"
                android:scheme="http" />
            <data
                android:host="www.myapp.com"
                android:path="/blog"
                android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
```

But this didn't helped.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. Notice that _host_ and _path_ are case sensitive. Is it only the link `myapp.com/blog` or something like `myapp.com/blog?id=234`?

Comment: Now I am trying the simplest case just to launch myapp.com/blog.

Comment: Your code should work for `myapp.com/blog`. To get `myapp.com/blog?...` to work, replace **path** with **pathPrefix**.